# Web browser application running javascript, will idle and stop processing in Chrome after Windows 10 lock

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, javascript

A website written in JavaScript with a loop, times out on windows when windows 10 lock screen comes up.  When a person logs backs in, JavaScript will then continue, as if it did not stop.

So this applications just loops and grabs data, and sends data to API endpoints in a synchronous manner.  On my home personal computer given to my by my employer there are no problems, does not lock out after 15 minutes because we use AWS workstations when working etc.  This was designed to work from any computer with an internet connection, with a username and password and TFA.

I have gone into Chromes performance setting and turned of idling tabs, and even added exceptions(due to I noticed Chrome after update, it seems to turn this setting back on) Now that we are concerned with saving energy and the planet etc.

We have tried using Edge,Firefox and its the same engine so same problems.  I have asked the support team to just give them a computer, that supports a web browser, and does not lock out, as it needs to access to anything but the internet, no local resources etc.  They responded with giving the users a machine they can RDP into and installed Microsoft's anti idling program.  (This still doesn't work) As i explained this a terminal session and not the console, so any mouse program would be useless, and is still idling out.

I have tried to search the internet for this issue, but its difficult as the results seem to come back about a completely different issue.  All that needs to be done is a PC, dmzed, and turn off the lock screen.  But not getting anywhere, they don't feel the pain, me and the users do though, as well as the owners and their revenue.

Is there anything I am missing to get a browser to keep chugging away if windows locks? Yes making this an exe would work, but when this was built this issue did not happen and surprised this seems new?

FYI they also need access to this machine remotely, I brought up vpc but was turned down as its insecure, but yet RDP is fine?

I was thinking maybe Safari might help or some other web JavaScript engine a person can navigate with that doesn't have all such overhead as a full browser.

Comment: Your description of the problem is unclear. Could we have a more concise text describing just your setup and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You can simply disable the lock screen https://www.howtogeek.com/270493/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-in-windows-10/ A neater solution would be to have a server somewhere running it instead of a browser window. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently
https://blog.logrocket.com/running-node-js-scripts-continuously-forever/

Comment: Firefox and Chromium-based browsers do not share the same engine. // Are you _absolutely certain_ the PC does not sleep?

Comment: I can’t disable the Lock Screen it’s security for the company. I have tried Firefox, and edge same issue. I guess can use the web browser inside and exe but uncertain if the same problem will occur

Comment: Logrocket looks interesting but a user needs to authenticate , in cognito and tfa

Answer (score 0):

Well i just ended up creating a WinForms app with a webbrowser inside the form as a work around to this issue.

I cannot say this is indeed the answer, but it works and ignores web engine timeouts when screen locks out or browser tabs are unused or minimized